# Launch VLC in Electron on first load

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to launch VLC in Electron using `child_process`:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const child                  = require('child_process');

require('electron-reload')();

function createWindow () {
    
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    win.loadFile('index.html');
    
}

function launchVLC () {
    
    var proc = child.spawn("vlc");

}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow).then(launchVLC);
```

After running:

```
npm run start
```

I'm getting a ENOENT error:

[image]

I'm using Windows 10.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the correct path to the program. As the error says, the path doesn't exist:

#### `main.js`

```
const path = require('path')

function getDefaultVlcPath () {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    return path.join('C:', 'Program Files (x86)', 'VideoLAN', 'VLC', 'vlc.exe')
  }
  else if (process.platform === 'linux') {
    return '/usr/bin/vlc'
  }
  else if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    return '/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC'
  }
}

function getVlcPath () {
  // If the user specified custom VLC path
  // use that instead of the default one
  if (settings.customVlcPath) {
    return settings.customVlcPath
  }
  else {
    return getDefaultVlcPath()
  }
}


child.spawn(getVlcPath())
```

#### `yourSettingsFile.json`

```js
{
  settings.customVlcPath: 'specified/custom/path/to/vlc'
}
```